# Is there any way to make Steam overlay work on flash/AIR-based games?

Tags: steam, macos

If my memory serves me right, I can play Anodyne and a bunch of other flash/AIR-based games on Windows **with** an overlay. Now, I'm on OS X and I can't seem to pinpoint any valid solutions. Is there a "hack" or a way to make it work on OS X?

Comment: Oh? As an avid *Binding of Isaac* player, I specifically recall that the overlay never ever worked for me on my Windows PC...

Comment: @Aubergine: There are some games where it works and some games where it doesn't. VVVVVV supported it when it was still Flash-based (the current C++ version doesn't, though), Defender's Quest also supports it. I'm not entirely sure what causes this difference; maybe it has something to do with the AIR runtime.

Comment: Rogue Legacy doesn't seem to support it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam distributes different versions of the game you're playing depending on what system you are on. As developer Edmund McMillen has said about his game The Binding of Isaac (another flash based game) earlier, it **takes quite a bit of fixing from the developer's side** in order to make the Steam overlay (and, in some cases, achievements) work in flash games on OSX.

Unless Seagaia (developer of Anodyne) and the other developers of the games you are referring to decide to properly implement/fix the Steam overlay for OSX, **the overlay will not work on OSX**.

Comment: FYI, you can use the "flag" button to ask a moderator to fix it when you accidentally post an answer as a community wiki. Just for next time. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Huh, okay. This'll do for this time though, I guess. I would have gotten away with it if it wasn't for these nosy mods and their stinkin' dog!

Comment: Yeah, it'll do fine. +1 for the great answer too, by the way!